# Purchase steam sale games outside of steam store?

Tags: steam

I am trying to purchase a few games before the end of Steam 2016 Winter sales.
I tried on different devices with different cards, I also tried both the stand-alone and browser versions, and tried in different browsers and after several reboots, however after the paypal/credit card page, once returning to steam store's "purchase + review" page, nothing happens, the buttons keep being grayed out with the wordings "Working" on them.
I contacted steam support, and received no answer.

I am wondering: is there is an alternate method I can use to purchase steam games in sale, apart from the steam store (since their technology seems to have problems coping with their offer)?

Comment: Make sure that the previous attempts are not deducted from your card. Just because Steam does not give a confirmation does not mean your payment isn't processed.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the advice! Fortunately, paypal did not register any transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You do not receive Steam sale discounts when buying a Steam key through a different platform. Different platforms may offer their own discounts though. As far as I know there are no official Steam key resellers. Some sites may be able to offer Steam keys via the developers or publisher of the game, through a bundle discount or negotiated price. Some "marketplace" type sites may offer Steam keys based on fencing stolen goods, or by reselling keys bought earlier for a discount for any reason. You may also be able to buy a game directly from a developer, or publisher, and receive a stand-alone or Steam version of a game that way.

In your case, it sounds like you authorized the payment through PayPal, and you must treat this situation as if the money is successfully paid. Steam may try to verify and complete the transaction when their systems are no longer under extreme load.

Steam will save unpaid "carts" of games for 72 hours when they are not paid, and will keep the discounts applied to them. When you open the Steam client you should see indicated that there are still items in your cart. You will also receive an email with that information when Steam detects that there was an error with a recently done purchase. When you receive this email it is safe to retry buying your cart with games.

Comment: Not all stores that sell discounted Steam copies of games are based on stolen keys or the resale of keys from earlier sales.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there are no official resellers of steam keys. I never implied that keys must have been bought through previous sales. They can come from the developer/publisher, or be bought from a different region for a reduced price. It is unlikely someone (person/company) sells a steam key for less than the price on steam if they payed more for it.

Comment: You can't _buy_ Steam _keys_ via Steam; the license is directly added to the account the game is purchased for, or it is added to the account's inventory in the form of a gift item. The answer heavily implies that _any store selling keys is doing shady business_ by either stealing or reselling keys, but that's not really the case.

Comment: I would add that if this problem is not related to heavy load on the servers (ie it's an account or payment issue) and you are confident the transactions will not go through (or that you will be able to use Steam's refund system), you could also try having a friend purchase them as gifts.